# in html5, using INPUT type='date' versus DATE - nevermind

Tags: javascript, html, dom, input, w3c

This question is *moot* - see @Alochi comments.  my bad.

This is different than `button` in that `button` is a defined tag in the specs, whereas other types, `date, tel, password, hidden, ...`, are not but in practice *can* be used to create html. ([this](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/states-of-the-type-attribute.html#states-of-the-type-attribute) is the best link I can find).

from my experiments, on modern browsers the following are equivalent:

```
a = document.createElement('input');
a.type = 'date';
b = document.createElement('date');
```

`a` and `b` render the same and have the same attributes. *wrong*!! do *not* render the same

the big difference is that `querySelector` is *strict* - even though `date` might be equivalent to `input[type='date']` functionally, an element created with `date` will not be found with `input[type='date']` and vice versa.

in dealing with these guys it seems like we're going to need two sets queries if we're looking for them - or is there some superset that makes it easier?

is this a case where implementers are outrunning the specs?  it seems they are migrating all of the types to their own element, much like they did with `button` for example.

(assuming one does not care about legacy browsers) are there any guiding principles here?

Comment: Where did you find the `date` element? There's no `date` element in HTML5 and hasn't been for several years (although early drafts did contain one).

Comment: in chrome, for example, can create an INPUT type element with any of the types

Comment: this does _not_ work in firefox, so maybe chrome is way out of ordinary

Comment: Sure. And you can create a date element either with createElement or `<date>`. But it's not HTML5. And it won't behave like a form control.

Comment: @Alochi - you are absolutely right - I was being misled by chrome's creating the objects and careless in my testing.  can you please put as answer to put this question out of it's misery?

Comment: Feel free to accept flying sheep's answer. It pretty much covers the same ground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you get that about the `date` tag from?

There is no such tag, look:

- http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_reference.asp
- http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html

in the “block level semantics”, there is only `time`, in the section about forms, there is `input type="date"`, as well as tags like `button`, `keygen` and `meter`

but no `<date>` anywhere.

Comment: Try to avoid references to w3schools. Although it no longer lists `<date>`, IIRC it did so for years after it had been dropped from the HTML5 draft.

Comment: that's what I was asking.  standard is INPUT type='date', but chrome has extended html with all of these types, eg, DATE, RADIO, CHECKBOX, etc.  firefox, as usual, is sticking to the standards.  are chrome's actions where the process is heading, or are they out in left field on tis one?

Comment: you didn’t say that. you said “on modern browsers”, and firefox certainly is one :D i don’t know what the future looks like, but the different appearace of all input tags suggests to me that they should use separate tags, as well. but that’s my opinion; the future will tell.

Comment: the entire basis for my question was misplaced.  chrome allows `document.createElement('date')` but it's a useless element, not at all the INPUT type='date' as I had incorrectly assumed.  FF, on the other hand, makes `document.createElement('date')` simply illegal.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen the date picker in Opera as `<input type="date">` see the small box in top left at http://www.shaneofalltrades.com/electrical.html if you have Opera. I loaded this just for sample, no process with it. Also works in Safari but with only a simpler form and does not work in IE9 or Firefox 6.